# Like button for images is not working

Tags: php

I am making an online photo gallery app for my university project. I would like to include a like button on images.

Here's an HTML embedded within PHP tags:

```
echo "<div class='middle'><div class='likeButton'><form method='post'><input 
class='likeButtonStyle' type='submit' value='likeFunc()' name='like' /></form>
</div></div>";
```

Here's the function I was trying to use:

```
$like = 0;
if ( isset($_POST['like']) ) {
    function likeFunc() {
        $like = $like + 1;
        echo $like;
    }
}
```

Comment: And how exactly is this failing?

Comment: @David It's saying the whole function name as the value of the button like this: "likeFunc()"

Comment: Well, that's the value you set: `value='likeFunc()'`  PHP isn't going to automatically execute PHP code that's inside your string.  Did you mean to use the `$like` variable instead?  Something like: `value='" . $like . "'`  It's also not clear what you expect that function to really be doing, since it's *echoing* a value instead of returning it.

Comment: @David Thank you, sir! You solved my problem. I am feeling really dumb now :) Another thing I want to achieve is that how can I update the counter. Currently, it's showing 0 that it should be. The problem is if I click the button it's refreshing the page simply because I am using a form here thus setting the value again to 0, but if I don't use a form I can't use $_POST['like']. Is there anyway you would like to recommend?

Comment: If you want the counter value to outlive a single page then you'll need to persist that value somewhere.  Session would work for very short term storage, a database for more persistent storage.

Comment: @David I just did it! Working great! Now time to figure out to detect which image like button was clicked! Thank you for your help ^.^

Answer (score 0):

Do not embed the action within a function and never call it. To manipulate what you already have to make it work simply put `likeFunc();` below the closing `}` in the function declaration. I see that you are trying to call via a form value, to do this try using the `call_user_func` within PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php
Hope this helps and makes sense.
-Aaron

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call the function you created. You can try changing your code to look more like this.

```
<?php 
    $like = 0;
    function likeFunc() {
        global $like;
        $like = $like + 1;
        echo $like;
    }
    if ( isset($_POST['like']) ) {
        likeFunc();
    }
?>
<div class='middle'><div class='likeButton'>
<form method='post'>
<input class='likeButtonStyle' type='submit' value='like' name='like' />
</form>
</div>
</div>
```